# is there a possibility to import documents in bulk on alfresco

Tags: metadata, alfresco

is there a possibility to in bulk import documents and their metadata in alfresco. In fact what I want is upload a bunch of documents and inject their metadata from a xml file.
thanks in advance

Comment: search it on google or in their official docs may be? https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/Bulk-Import-Tool.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer I've read the documentation there but what I want to know is the possibility of associating (in batch) of metadata(I have in an excel file) to these documents whitout having to enter each uploaded document and fill the metadata fields

Answer (score 1):

The link that Abbas pointed you to is the best option. The Bulk File System Import Tool supports bulk importing content as well as metadata.

Write a script that exports your spreadsheet into the format the BFSIT expects. Then upload your content and each of the content's metadata descriptor files (generated from your spreadsheet) to the server. Finally, run the import.

If instead what you are trying to do is not import files and metadata but instead you just want to set metadata from your spreadsheet on a bunch of existing content that is already in the repository, then what you can do is write a script that reads your spreadsheet and uses something like Python cmislib or OpenCMIS (both are from [Apache Chemistry](https://chemistry.apache.org)) to set that metadata on objects in the repository in bulk.

You can also use CMIS to upload files, but the BFSIT is much more efficient.